# React Native - Create custom text input field component and handle onChangeText in there

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I am using React Native with Expo and **React Native Paper** as the styling library.

React Native Paper provides a *TextInput* Component and a *HelperText* Component. You can combine these 2 components and have the HelperText show errors or info messages based on the user input in the TextInput component associated with it.

I am trying to create my own custom Component so it encapsulates these two different Components into one, I call my custom Component *TextInputWithHelperText*.

I am trying to implement this on a Login page that I am working on, and the code that I have is something like this:

LoginPage:

```
// Imports...

export default function LoginPage() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('test@email.com');
    const [emailHasErrors, setEmailHasErrors] = useState(false);
    const [emailValidationErrorMessage, setEmailValidationErrorMessage] = useState('');

    const handleLogin = async () => {
      // Assume that some email validation results in the following states to change
      setEmailHasErrors(true);
      setEmailValidationErrorMessage('Invalid Email');
    };

    return (
          <View>
              <TextInputWithHelperText
                  label='Email'
                  value={email}
                  onChangeText={input => setEmail(input)}
                  helperTextVisible={emailHasErrors}
                  helperTextType='error'
                  helperTextMessage={emailValidationErrorMessage}
              />
          </View>
          <View>
              <Button mode="contained" onPress={handleLogin}> Login </Button>
          </View>
    )
```

TextInputWithHelperText:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextInput, HelperText } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function TextInputWithHelperText({ ...props }) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);

    return (
       <>
          <TextInput
            label={props.label}
            value={props.value}
            onChangeText={(inputText) => { setValue(inputText) }}
          />
          <HelperText
            type={props.helperTextType}
            visible={props.helperTextVisible}
          >
            {props.helperTextMessage}
          </HelperText>
       </>
    )
}
```

**The problem:**

The problem occurs on the **onChangeText** property.

Currently, the way it is, causes the **setEmail(input)** to never be invoked despite the fact that I can see the input text changing in the UI. This results to the *test@email.com* value that I set as default, to be sent to the backend as email value each time the login button is clicked.

**Things I tried:**

Another solution that I tried, was passing to the TextInputWithHelperText Component's onChangeText prop, the onChangeText prop passed down by the parent Component, something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextInput, HelperText } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function TextInputWithHelperText({ ...props }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);

  return (
     <>
        <TextInput
          label={props.label}
          value={props.value}
          onChangeText={props.onChangeText}    <--------- THE CHANGE
        />
        <HelperText
          type={props.helperTextType}
          visible={props.helperTextVisible}
        >
          {props.helperTextMessage}
        </HelperText>
     </>
  )
}
```

This indeed caused the **setEmail(input)** to be called each time there is a text change, but in the UI I could only see the last letter that I typed. Also the value of the **email** was also set to the last letter typed each time.

**Question:**

How can I keep the UI updating on each text change but also having the **email** value updating as well in the LoginPage Component?

P.S. I have omitted parts of the code since they were not necessary for the point of the question.